# why my wordpress plugin is not showing sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm programming a **plugin** in php for wordpress for managing widgets, their places in a page and in which page they should appear. I'm having problems because i can't activate my sidebar and i dont know why. I post my code to see if something is not right and you can help me. this first file is the functions.php that, in theory, should register sidebars.

```
require_once('widgets.php');
function my_register_sidebars(){
    // Register the 'primary' sidebar. 
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'id' => 'primary',
      'name' => __('Primary Sidebar'),
      'description' => __('A short description of the sidebar.'),
      'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
      'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
      'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
  );
  register_sidebar(
    array(
      'id' => 'adios',
      'name' => __('adios'),
      'description' => __('A short description of the sidebar.'),
      'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
      'after_widget' => '</div>',
      'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
      'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
  );
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars');
```

after a series of try-outs, I have also seen that add_action is not doing his work, do you have answers about it?
After that i instantiated a new file(sidebar.php) to recall the sidebar.

```
<?php
if (is_active_sidebar('primary')) : ?>
    <aside id="secondary" class="sidebar widget-area" role="complementary" style="background-color = 'black';">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('primary'); ?>
    </aside><!-- .sidebar .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

And finally to call the sidebar i use get_sidebar();
but i cannot show the sidebar and it seems it is not even active. 
do you have also ideas on how i can add widgets to this "activated" sidebar?
Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your function.php

```
function my_custom_sidebar() {
register_sidebar(
    array (
        'name' => __( 'Custom', 'your-theme-domain' ),
        'id' => 'custom-side-bar',
        'description' => __( 'Custom Sidebar', 'your-theme-domain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-content">',
        'after_widget' => "</div>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    )
);} add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_sidebar' );
```

And put this code to your template file

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ) ) : ?>
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-side-bar' ); ?>
```

Try This code

Comment: it's not working and if i try to add a widget it becomes inactive